# How do I print multiple lines to the screen when creating an operating system?

Tags: c, operating-system

I have been trying to learn the basics of creating an operating system in C and have managed to finally print a character to the screen:

http://i63.tinypic.com/6ftesp.png

Here is the meat of the program I wrote up:

```
#include "font.h"

void console_putc(char ch){
    volatile unsigned* serialport = (unsigned*) 0x16000000;
    volatile unsigned* serialflags = (unsigned*) 0x16000018;
    while( *serialflags & 32 )
        ;
    *serialport = ch;
}


struct PL110MMIO {
    unsigned haxis;         //offset 0: horizontal axis                             
    unsigned vaxis;         //offset 4: vertical axis                               
    unsigned polarity;      //offset 8: clock+polarity                              
    unsigned lineend;       //offset 12: line end
    unsigned baseaddr1;     //offset 16: upper panel base address                           
    unsigned baseaddr2;     //offset 20: lower panel base address
    unsigned intmask;       //offset 24: interrupt mask
    unsigned params;        //offset 28: panel parameters   
};

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600

#define framebuffer ((volatile unsigned short*) (((0x07ffffff - WIDTH*HEIGHT*2))&~0xf)) //0x200000;
#define pl110 ( (volatile struct PL110MMIO*)0xc0000000 )

void console_init(){

    //To get screen width w: 0x3f1f3f00 | (w/4-4)
    //ex: 640 = 0x3f1f3f9c
    pl110->haxis = 0x3f1f3f00 | (WIDTH/ 4-4);

    //To get screen height v: 0x80b600 | (v-1) 
    //Ex: 480 = 0x80b61df
    pl110->vaxis = 0x80b6000 | (HEIGHT-1)   ;

    pl110->polarity = 0x067f3800;
    pl110->baseaddr1 = (unsigned) framebuffer;

    //value         bpp
    //0x1821        1
    //0x1823        2
    //0x1825        4
    //0x1827        8
    //0x1829        16
    //0x182b        24
    pl110->params = 0x1829;

}

void set_pixel(int x, int y, unsigned short color){
    framebuffer[ y*WIDTH+x ] = color;
}

//input: r,g,b in range 0...255 
//output: 16 bit color with 565 weighting
#define COLOR16(r,g,b) ( ((b&0xf8)<<8) | ((g & 0xfc)<<3) | ((r&0xf8)>>3) )

void console_box( int x, int y, int w, int h ){
    int i;
    unsigned short color = COLOR16( 0,128,255 );

    for(i=0;i<w;++i){
        set_pixel(x+i,y,color);
        set_pixel(x+i,y+h,color);
    }
    for(i=0;i<h;++i){
        set_pixel(x,y+i,color);
        set_pixel(x+w,y+i,color);
    }
}

void console_set_pixel(int x, int y, unsigned short color){
    framebuffer[ y*WIDTH+x ] = color;
}

void console_draw_character(int x, int y, unsigned short color, char c){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<CHAR_HEIGHT;++i){
        for(j=0;j<CHAR_WIDTH;++j){
            if( font_data[(int)c][i] & (MASK_VALUE >> j) ) 
                framebuffer[ (y+i)*WIDTH + (x+j) ] = color;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am attempting to expand on this to print multiple characters to the screen (without scrolling...yet...I am not going to try and tackle this as of right now) like this:

http://i68.tinypic.com/2urv6tx.png (Please excuse my terrible MSPaint skills. I wanted to make it clear it was the text I am trying to display. Also, yes, the Gettysburg Address is the text. I just went to a Civil War reenactment and it is stuck in my head.)

Since one can give a row and column for where the character is aligned, I am thinking I can increment it every time I get a \t, \n, or \b with something like:

```
// For a new line character of course
if(c=='\n'){
    row++;
    col = 0;
else{
    draw_char;
    col++;
    // For wrapping the text to the next line when it goes to the edge of the screen
    if(col > 799){
        row++;
        col=0;
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to represent the other characters though (for example, how to remove a character with backspace and how to add 4 spaces with tab (just increment the column four times? This comes out....strange.))

So my question in short is: **How do I handle multiple characters being printed to the operating system screen including special characters like newline and tab?**

Comment: backspace can be emulated with filling a rectangle with background pixels... tabs is like space but stops at tabstops. Your logic fro wrapping is wrong, you should wrap before emitting the char, not emit the char then wrap. In fact, you should better proceed with a buffer that contains all the chars on screen (a grid) and emit a drawing refresh for the whole each time (some optimization can be made if needed).

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès Losing the single character does not matter too much as I am just trying to get anything on the screen, but thank you for the tip there. As for backspace, do you mean for the number of pixels (ex. 3), make a 3 pixel wide rectangle of in this case black to simulate it?

Comment: Yes that's it. Could you imagine something else than erasing the space allocated for a char?